# How to Get Dataset as a response from webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to get the dataset as a response from webapi for that I am internally implementing Interface class which has concrete implementation.Can any one suggest me how to do that

I tried getting dataset as a response from webapi

I Expect the output as Dataset if I call webapi method

Comment: what have you tried? where is the actual problem? start here please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can not get dataset as a response from webapi. Web API will give you response in JSON or XML (depending upon request) format. After getting the response you can convert it to dataset.

Answer (score 0):

we cannot pass the DataSet response in web API, but we can get the Dataset response from DB, and then you need to map that data to the model and pass it to the caller. in JSON format.

```
 public DataSet GetIssue(int intIssueID)
    {
        var _connSting = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection");
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connSting))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAssetForIssue", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IssueID", intIssueID);
            SqlDataAdapter _dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();
            _dataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet);
            return _dataSet;
        }
    }
```